# Efficient solution for quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(x-2)(x-3) + (x-3)(x+1) + (x + 1)(x-2) = 0$ and $r, s$ are the roots, then what must be the value of $$\frac{1}{(r-1)(s-1)} + \frac{1}{(r-2)(s-2)} + \frac{1}{(r-3)(s-3)}$$

My only known solution is to manually solve for $r$ and $s$, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

On simplification,

$$3x^2-x(5+2-1)+6-3-2=0$$

Use Vieta's formula to find $rs, r+s$

Now $(r-u)(s-u)=rs-(r+s)u+u^2$

Here $u=1,2,3$

Comment: Tnx a lot i got ur idea :)